# Error en programa sencillo de C++

Tags: c++, array

tengo un programa sencillo en C++, solo quiero sumar unos números varias veces entre ellos pero el problema es que me lanza este error:

> [nombre_del_programa].exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Y el codigo del programa es este:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char tecla=0;
    int *arrayNumeros;

    short unsigned cantidad = 0;
    std::cout << "Cantidad de numeros a evaluar\n";
    std::cin >> cantidad;

    arrayNumeros = new int(cantidad);

    for (short i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        std::cout << "Ingresa un numero\n";
        std::cin >> arrayNumeros[i];        
    }
    for (short i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        for (short j = 0; j < cantidad; j++) {          
            if (i == j)
                continue;
            else {
                int suma = arrayNumeros[i];
                suma += arrayNumeros[j];

                std::cout << suma;

                //std::cout << "\nLa Suma de " << arrayNumeros[i] << " y " << arrayNumeros[j] << " = " << suma;
            }           
        }
    }
    std::cout << "ADIOS";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

El error se presenta cuando no pongo ningún breakpoint (hasta me da el error en el `cout<< suma;`) si le dejo algún breakpoint y sigo toda la secuencia me imprime sin errores los números pero al llegar al `return 0;` me salta el error. El compilador que uso es Visual Studio 2015. Sé que existe el 2019 pero no sé porque ahora el 2015 me da estos errores si antes no lo hacía.

PD: No pido nada en cuánto a optimización de código, que seguro habrá detalles que sí.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos en qué línea colocas el breakpoint? La versión de Visual Studio no tiene ninguna incidencia en esto, la versión del compilador no tiene que ver con la versión de tu entorno de desarrollo.

Comment: Yo lo he compilado y ejecutado y no me da ningún problema. ¿Has probado a ejecutar el programa directamente desde una consola en vez de ejecutarlo desde Visual Studio? Si te funciona en una consola, algo tienes configurado en Visual Studio que hace que te salga ese mensaje. Por otro lado, cuando haces new del array de enteros, dado que es un array deberías hacer `new int[ cantidad]` y no `new int( cantidad)`. Y luego tendrás que hacer el `delete [] arrayNumeros` para liberar la memoria reservada para el array.

Comment: Disculpen la tardanza, crasheo el SO de mi laptop y hasta el dia de hoy pude ponerme al punto con todo. 
La linea donde coloco el breakpoint sería en la 16, donde empieza el segundo for.
No he intentado ejecutarlo en una consola tal cual, solo desde el Visual Studio , pero creo es acertado el comentario que dices de la creación del array con los corchetes []. Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás accediendo a memoria que no te corresponde en el bucle de recopilación de datos:

```
for (short i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
    std::cout << "Ingresa un numero\n";
    std::cin >> arrayNumeros[i];        
}
```

Esto se debe a que `arrayNumeros` es un único entero:

```
arrayNumeros = new int(cantidad);
```

La instrucción anterior crea un puntero a **UN** `int` cuyo valor inicial será `cantidad`, si quieres reservar memoria para varios `int`, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
//                    vvvvvvvvvv <-- Se pedirá espacio para 'cantidad' enteros.
arrayNumeros = new int[cantidad]{};
//                              ^^ <-- Lista vacía: todos los elementos se inicializan a '0'.
```

La sintaxis para crear formaciones en memoria dinámica mediante `new` es:

```
new tipo[tamaño]{valores iniciales};
```

Los corchetes para el tamaño, las llaves para los elementos. La sintaxis para borrar la memoria solicitada (que **debes borrar la memoria que pides**) es `delete[] puntero;` los corchetes son importantes.

La sintaxis para crear un solo elemento (no una formación de elementos) en memoria dinámica mediante `new` es:

```
new tipo(argumentos del constructor);
```

Los paréntesis para los argumentos del constructor. La sintaxis para borrar la memoria solicitada (que **debes borrar la memoria que pides**) es `delete puntero;`.

---

Pero ya que estás trabajando en C++ te aconsejo que utilices las herramientas del mismo, no uses punteros en crudo, usa contenedores:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    short unsigned cantidad = 0;
    std::cout << "Cantidad de numeros a evaluar\n";
    std::cin >> cantidad;

    // Un vector de 'cantidad' elementos inicializados a '0'.
    std::vector<int> Numeros(cantidad, 0);

    for (auto &valor : Numeros) {
        std::cout << "Ingresa un numero\n";
        std::cin >> valor;
    }

    // …
    // Hacer cosas con los datos
    // …

    std::cout << "ADIOS";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es cierto. Se me olvidó que los paréntesis son para el constructor.Gracias por la sugerencia de usar vector.